# How do you add a web reference in VS 2019 VB SQL CLR project?

Tags: visual-studio-2019

I'm building a new VB SQL CLR project (stored procedure) and I'd like to add some web references

In VS 2017 (and earlier versions) I would just right click on the "References" of the Solution Explorer of my project and see in the drop down a "Web Reference" option.  In VS 2019, it is not there.

Nothing shows up in the drop down for a adding a web reference off of the "References" like it did in VS 2017.  Is this a limitation in doing a SQL CLR project, if so, is there a workaround?